# Can't execute jar : no main manifest attribute

Tags: log4j, gerrit

I recently encountered a log4j version 1.2.17 within the gerrit application hosted on an EC2 instance.
To remove this, I decompressed gerrit.war using

```
jar -xvf gerrit.war
rm -rf WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

And then repackaged the gerrit.war file using

```
jar -cvf gerrit.war *
```

I've also pasted the war file contents, if it might prove useful

```
drwxr-xr-x WEB-INF
-rwxr--r-- robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x polygerrit_ui
drwxr-xr-x META-INF
-rwxr--r-- Main.class
-rwxr--r-- LICENSES.txt
drwxr-xr-x gerrit_ui
drwxr-xr-x gerrit-launcher
-rwxr--r-- favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x Documentation
drwxr-xr-x com
-rwxr--r-- build-data.properties
```

Before repackaging the .war post log4j jar removal the MANIFEST.MF file had the class name

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: blaze-singlejar
Main-Class: Main
```

What I cannot see then in the META-INF\MANIFEST.MF file after removing the log4j jar is the Main Class. Essentially it looks like

```
$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_312 (Red Hat, Inc.)
```

Hence after running

```
java -jar gerrit.war init -d /var/gerrit/review
```

I'm receiving the "no main manifest attribute" error. I do not have the source code present as the .war file was taken from the gerrit site, as mentioned in the install steps.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `jar` use `zip`, which does not mess with the file's manifest.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for the suggestion. This worked fine :) However as I was suspecting, I'm now getting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout.

Comment: You need to replace the SLF4J to Log4j 1.x binding (`log4j-slf4j12`) with something else. For example the [SLF4J to Log4j 2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/) binding with its dependencies. Remark also that the Log4j 1.x project has been restarted by the original author: see [reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch/).